# SyntaxError: Parse error while running vue component tests with karma and webpack

Tags: unit-testing, webpack, vue.js, karma-jasmine

Im trying to run unit tests for vue components. I'm using babel parser to load the vue files.

This is my karma-config file:

```js
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js')
delete webpackConfig.entry

// karma.conf.js
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    // this is the entry file for all our tests.
    files: ['test/index.js'],
    // we will pass the entry file to webpack for bundling.
    preprocessors: {
      'test/index.js': ['webpack']
    },
    // use the webpack config
    webpack: webpackConfig,
    // avoid walls of useless text
    webpackMiddleware: {
      noInfo: true
    },
    singleRun: true
  })
}
```

This is my webpack config file:

```js
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './main.js',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue'
      },
      {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'babel',
    include: [
        path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
        path.join(__dirname, 'test')
    ],
    exclude: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
}
   ]
}
}
```

This is the unit test file:

```js
// test/component-a.spec.js
var Vue = require('vue')
var ComponentA = require('./a.vue')

describe('a.vue', function () {

  // asserting JavaScript options
  it('should have correct message', function () {
    expect(ComponentA.data().msg).toBe('Hello from Component A!')
  })

  // asserting rendered result by actually rendering the component
  it('should render correct message', function () {
    var vm = new Vue({
      template: '<div><test></test></div>',
      components: {
        'test': ComponentA
      }
    }).$mount()
    expect(vm.$el.querySelector('h2.red').textContent).toBe('Hello from Component A!')
  })
})
```

When running tests using `-> karma start karma.conf.js`, its throwing this parse error:

```
14 11 2016 19:15:36.808:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.3.0 server started at http://localhost:9876/
14 11 2016 19:15:36.812:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
14 11 2016 19:15:36.873:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
14 11 2016 19:15:40.126:INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#8Hrp1VoJHm1Y6JW9AAAA with id 58972703
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  SyntaxError: Parse error
  at test/index.js:6341
```

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates there is a parse error in your code at line 6341 of index.js. Because you have not labeled a file index.js, and have not included line numbers it is not possible to say with certainty what the specific cause of this error is. However, I can tell you that you need to look at line 6341 of index.js and check there for things like missing brackets or semi-colons, and also to check the surrounding code, as sometimes errors reported on one line are actually caused by a syntax error earlier in the document. Also, to check any other files which might be called on that line of index.js. Other than that, I'd suggest you include the contents of index.js in your question, if you've not done so already, label it index.js and include the line numbers. This will make it possible to tell you more specifically how to fix the problem.

Comment: index.js contains only   var testsContext = require.context('.', true, /\.spec$/)
testsContext.keys().forEach(testsContext)

Comment: there is no 6341 line in index.js

Comment: Ah. My guess then, would be one of two things: either webpack has created a file with 6341 or more lines after packaging and called it index.js (checked the webpacked file to see...) or there is a syntax error near the end of the file that's causing empty lines to be parsed as new lines for some reason (unlikely). Those are the things I'd check first.